# IMPORT ERROR when importing from sklearn.ensemble?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, import, classification, jupyter

I received an import error when importing the HistGradientBooostingClassifier from sklearn.ensemble

I typed in jupyter notebook:

'from sklearn.ensemble import HistGradientBoostingClassifier'

[image: screenshot of the error].

Comment: [*Please do not post text as images*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool (`{}` button) to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, cannot be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments, and cannot be copied for testing and debugging purposes. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: Thank you noted. I edited my post and add curly braces. It helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first result from a (US) Google search for `ImportError from sklearn.ensemble import HistGradientBoostingClassifier` is [this issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/15079) from the `scikit-learn` repo on Github.

> HistGradientBoostingRegressor is experimental. You need to enable experimental features first:

```
from sklearn.experimental import enable_hist_gradient_boosting
from sklearn.ensemble import HistGradientBoostingRegressor
```